# Formulario actualizado PHP - HTML

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo un formulario para **añadir datos a una tabla** (visual en HTML) **y a la base de datos** (en una tabla llamada "Cabanas").

**Dudas:**

1) **¿Por qué no se actualiza automáticamente la tabla al pulsar "Guardar"?** Y sólo se ve la cabaña agregada cuando actualizamos la página.

2) Cuando actualizamos vemos que inserta la cabaña correctamente pero le da un ID=0, cuando todos los IDs en mi tabla empiezan de (1-N) y se regeneran automáticamente. Es decir, **a todas las cabañas que quiero agregar le asigna el ID=0**, es decir, sólo me permite agregar una sino da error de "duplicate primary key".

**Código SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE CABANAS (
    idcabana INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    capacidad INT NOT NULL, 
    descripcion VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    precio DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL, /*Precio: cabaña/noche */
    CHECK (capacidad>0 AND capacidad<=10)
);

INSERT INTO CABANAS (idcabana, nombre, capacidad, descripcion, precio) VALUES 
(1, "CABAÑA1", 9, "HABITACIÓN DE CABAÑA MUY GRANDE CON TODOS LOS ACCESORIOS.", 150),
(2, "CABAÑA2", 6, "CUATRO CAMAS CON CAPACIDAD PARA 7 PERSONAS. IDÓNEA PARA FAMILIAS.", 92),
(3, "CABAÑA3", 4, "DOS CAMAS, CON OPCIÓN A UNA SUPLETORIA. CABAÑA MUY CÓMODA Y AMIGABLE.", 78);
```

**Código HTML:**

```
<?php
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Cabanas.php";
    require_once "conexion.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "administrador"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
        $administrador = $_SESSION['administrador'];
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Panel del administrador</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sesion_administrador">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$administrador."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='salir_administrador.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>"; //GET
                //_REQUEST = $_POST o $_GET
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_administrador.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos_cabana" id="tabla_datos_cabana" method="POST">
            <div id="mostrar_cabanas">
            <br/><br/><br/>
                <table class="table table-striped" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
                    <center>
                        <tr>
                            <thead style="background-color:#A9F5A9">
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>ID Cabaña</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"250\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Nombre</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Modificar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Eliminar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                            </thead>
                        </tr>   
                        <?php
                        $datos = BD::obtenerCabanas();
                        foreach($datos as $cabana){
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getIdcabana()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"250\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getNombre()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>"?> 
                                    <a href="modificar.php?idcabana=<?=$cabana->getIdcabana();?>">
                                        <img src="imagenes/modificar.png" height='24' width='26' onmouseover="this.src='imagenes/modificar_in.png';" onmouseout="this.src='imagenes/modificar.png';">
                                    </a> <?php "</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value=".$cabana->getIdcabana()."></center>";
                         echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </center>
                </table>

                <!-- Botón NUEVA cabaña -->
                <div class="boton_anadir" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Añadir cabaña"></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <!-- Botón ELIMINAR cabaña/s -->
                <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');" value="Eliminar cabañas"></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "Eliminar cabañas"...
                if(isset($_POST['eliminar_cabanas'])){
                    if(empty($_POST['marcados'])){
                        echo "<h4><center>No se ha seleccionado ninguna cabaña.</center></h4>";
                    }else{
                        foreach($_POST['marcados'] as $valor){
                            //Nos conectamos a la base de datos.
                            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            //Realizamos la consulta.
                            $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana='%d'", $valor);
                            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                            /*
                            $mysqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana = ?");
                            $stmt->bind_param('i', $valor);
                            $stmt->execute(); 
                            $stmt->close();
                            */
                        }
                        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=panel_administrador.php\">";
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <!-- Añadir una cabaña -->
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="añadir_cabanas" id="añadir_cabanas" method="POST">
            <div id="añadir_cabanas">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label> <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"/></label><br/><br/>
                <label for="capacidad">Capacidad: </label>
                <?php
                echo "<select name='capacidad'>";
                for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                    if($i==1){
                        echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?><br/><br/>
                <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label> <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion"/></label><br/><br/>
                <label for="precio">Precio: </label> <input type="text" id="precio" name="precio"/></label><br/><br/>

                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="guardar" name="guardar"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Resetear" id="resetear" name="resetear"/>
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "Guardar"...
                if(isset($_POST["guardar"])){
                    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
                    $capacidad = $_POST["capacidad"];
                    $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
                    $precio = $_POST["precio"];
                    //Llamamos al método "anadirCabana" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
                    BD::anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio);
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código PHP función anadirCabana:**

```
static public function anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cabanas (nombre, capacidad, descripcion, precio) VALUES ('".$nombre."', ".$capacidad.", '".$descripcion."', ".$precio.")";
        $ok = $ejecucion->exec($sql);
        if($ok==1){
            echo "Cabaña agregada.";
        }else{
            echo "Cabaña NO agregada.";
        }
    }
```

3) ¿Cómo podría ponerse la siguiente instrucción de una forma más profesional para que no se muestre en pantalla los "echo" y vaya todo por detrás?

```
if($ok==1){
    echo "Cabaña agregada.";
}else{
    echo "Cabaña NO agregada.";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te respondo por puntos:

**1) ¿Por qué no se actualiza automáticamente la tabla al pulsar "Guardar"? Y sólo se ve la cabaña agregada cuando actualizamos la página.**

El motivo es que envías el formulario a la misma página donde muestras resultados, este código se ejecutará por orden linear, si muestras los resultados antes de llamar a la función `BD::anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio);` el resultado es que se realiza el `SELECT` para obtener las cabañas antes que el `INSERT`, ya que tu `INSERT` es el último proceso que se realiza en el fichero PHP. Te modifico el código:

```
<?php
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Cabanas.php";
    require_once "conexion.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "administrador"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
        $administrador = $_SESSION['administrador'];
    }

   //Si pulsamos el botón "Guardar"... 
   //EDITO: Se sube esta parte del código a la parte superior, para que se realice el insert antes que el select.
    if(isset($_POST["guardar"])){
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
        $capacidad = $_POST["capacidad"];
        $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
        $precio = $_POST["precio"];
        //Llamamos al método "anadirCabana" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
        BD::anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio);
    }
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Panel del administrador</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sesion_administrador">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$administrador."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='salir_administrador.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>"; //GET
                //_REQUEST = $_POST o $_GET
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_administrador.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos_cabana" id="tabla_datos_cabana" method="POST">
            <div id="mostrar_cabanas">
            <br/><br/><br/>
                <table class="table table-striped" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
                    <center>
                        <tr>
                            <thead style="background-color:#A9F5A9">
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>ID Cabaña</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"250\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Nombre</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Modificar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Eliminar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                            </thead>
                        </tr>   
                        <?php
                        $datos = BD::obtenerCabanas();
                        foreach($datos as $cabana){
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getIdcabana()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"250\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getNombre()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>"?> 
                                    <a href="modificar.php?idcabana=<?=$cabana->getIdcabana();?>">
                                        <img src="imagenes/modificar.png" height='24' width='26' onmouseover="this.src='imagenes/modificar_in.png';" onmouseout="this.src='imagenes/modificar.png';">
                                    </a> <?php "</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value=".$cabana->getIdcabana()."></center>";
                         echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </center>
                </table>

                <!-- Botón NUEVA cabaña -->
                <div class="boton_anadir" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Añadir cabaña"></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <!-- Botón ELIMINAR cabaña/s -->
                <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');" value="Eliminar cabañas"></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "Eliminar cabañas"...
                if(isset($_POST['eliminar_cabanas'])){
                    if(empty($_POST['marcados'])){
                        echo "<h4><center>No se ha seleccionado ninguna cabaña.</center></h4>";
                    }else{
                        foreach($_POST['marcados'] as $valor){
                            //Nos conectamos a la base de datos.
                            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            //Realizamos la consulta.
                            $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana='%d'", $valor);
                            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                            /*
                            $mysqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana = ?");
                            $stmt->bind_param('i', $valor);
                            $stmt->execute(); 
                            $stmt->close();
                            */
                        }
                        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=panel_administrador.php\">";
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <!-- Añadir una cabaña -->
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="añadir_cabanas" id="añadir_cabanas" method="POST">
            <div id="añadir_cabanas">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label> <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"/></label><br/><br/>
                <label for="capacidad">Capacidad: </label>
                <?php
                echo "<select name='capacidad'>";
                for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                    if($i==1){
                        echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?><br/><br/>
                <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label> <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion"/></label><br/><br/>
                <label for="precio">Precio: </label> <input type="text" id="precio" name="precio"/></label><br/><br/>

                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="guardar" name="guardar"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Resetear" id="resetear" name="resetear"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2) Cuando actualizamos vemos que inserta la cabaña correctamente pero le da un ID=0, cuando todos los IDs en mi tabla empiezan de (1-N) y se regeneran automáticamente. Es decir, a todas las cabañas que quiero agregar le asigna el ID=0, es decir, sólo me permite agregar una sino da error de "duplicate primary key".**

Si que has seteado el campo como primario y único, pero no como `auto-increment`, debes cambiar esa propiedad para poder hacer que se aumente automáticamente. El `SQL` sería:

```
ALTER TABLE CABANAS MODIFY COLUMN idcabana auto_increment
```

**3) ¿Cómo podría ponerse la siguiente instrucción de una forma más profesional para que no se muestre en pantalla los "echo" y vaya todo por detrás?**

No entiendo exactamente a que te refieres por detrás, pero si lo que no quieres es mostrar ningún valor cuando haces el proceso, no es necesario que hagas un echo:

```
static public function anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio){
    $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cabanas (nombre, capacidad, descripcion, precio) VALUES ('".$nombre."', ".$capacidad.", '".$descripcion."', ".$precio.")";
    $ok = $ejecucion->exec($sql);

    if($ok==1) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

En este caso, vamos a devolver `TRUE` o `FALSE`, ya que es recomendado para tener un control de nuestros procesos, que luego quieres mostrar algo ya verificas si la respuesta fue `TRUE` o `FALSE` para mostrar un mensaje, que no, no realizas dicha comprobación y no se muestra nada.

Saludos,

Comment: 1) ¿Esto significa que cuando hago la conexión a la función "anadirCabana(), seguidamente debo llamar de nuevo a "BD::obtenerCabanas();"?

Comment: No, quiere decir que debes subir el código que hace el insert a la parte superior, dame unos minutos que agrego el código a mi respuesta.

Comment: Cuando agregues código de ambas dudas (1 y 2), leo y te comento las dudas que tenga.

Comment: Listo, actualizado me comentas si te funcionó o si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: Todo correcto y entendido. En vez de realizar el ALTER TABLE he añadido a: idcabana INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL